# Merge partially overlapping date ranges in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose that I have two tables (`DT_sportA` and `DT_sportB`) that measure time periods in which two children (`id`) played sport "A" and "B".

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT_sportA <- data.table(id = rep(1:2,each=2),
                start_date = ymd(c("2000-01-01","2002-01-15","2014-03-12","2016-10-14")),
                end_date = ymd(c("2000-02-03","2003-03-01","2014-04-03","2017-05-19")))
DT_sportA
#    id start_date   end_date
# 1:  1 2000-01-01 2000-02-03
# 2:  1 2002-01-15 2003-03-01
# 3:  2 2014-03-12 2014-04-03
# 4:  2 2016-10-14 2017-05-19


DT_sportB <- data.table(id = c(1L,1L,2L),
                        start_date = ymd(c("2000-01-15","2002-01-15","2017-02-10")),
                        end_date = ymd(c("2000-02-01","2006-03-19","2017-02-20")))

DT_sportB
#    id start_date   end_date
# 1:  1 2000-01-15 2000-02-01
# 2:  1 2002-01-15 2006-03-19
# 3:  2 2017-02-10 2017-02-20
```

I would like to generate a new table with all of the unique and overlapping date ranges with two categorical indicators denoting the sport played by the children. The desired DT should look like this:

```
   id start_date   end_date sportA sportB
1:  1 2000-01-01 2000-01-14      1      0
2:  1 2000-01-15 2000-02-01      1      1
3:  1 2000-02-02 2000-02-03      1      0
4:  1 2002-01-15 2002-03-01      1      1
5:  1 2002-03-02 2002-03-19      0      1
6:  2 2014-03-12 2014-04-03      1      0
7:  2 2016-10-14 2017-02-09      1      0
8:  2 2017-02-10 2017-02-20      1      1
9:  2 2017-02-21 2017-05-19      1      0
```

This is a fairly trivial toy example. The real data spans several million rows and approximately 20 "sports", which is why I am looking for a `data.table` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes:

- when doing similar/same things to multiple tables, I find it is almost always preferable to operate on them as a [list of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227) instead of individual objects; while this solution will work in general without this (some adaptation required), I believe it makes many things worth the mind-shift;
- further, I actually think a long-format is better than a list-of-tables here, as we can still differentiate `id` and `sport` with ease;
- your expected output is a little inconsistent in how it avoids overlap between rows; for example, `"2000-01-14"` is not in the data, but it is the `end_date`, suggesting that `"2000-01-15"` was reduced because the next row starts on that date ... but there is a start on `"2000-02-02"` for apparently similar (but reversed) reasons; one way around this is to subtract a really low number from `end_date` so that no id/sport/date range will match multiple rows, and I say "low number" and not `1` because `Date`-class objects are really `numeric`, and dates can be fractional: though not displayed fractionally, it is still fractional, compare `Sys.Date()-0.1` with `dput(Sys.Date()-0.1)`.

```r
sports <- rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "DT_sport.*")), idcol = "sport")
sports[, sport := gsub("^DT_", "", sport) ] # primarily aesthetics
#     sport    id start_date   end_date
#    <char> <int>     <Date>     <Date>
# 1: sportA     1 2000-01-01 2000-02-03
# 2: sportA     1 2002-01-15 2003-03-01
# 3: sportA     2 2014-03-12 2014-04-03
# 4: sportA     2 2016-10-14 2017-05-19
# 5: sportB     1 2000-01-15 2000-02-01
# 6: sportB     1 2002-01-15 2006-03-19
# 7: sportB     2 2017-02-10 2017-02-20
```

I tend to like piping `data.table`, and since I'm still on R-4.0.5, I use `magrittr::%>%` for this; it is not strictly required, but I feel it helps readability (and therefore maintainability, etc). (I don't know if this will work as easily in R-4.1's native `|>` pipe, as that has more restrictions on the RHS data placement.)

```r
library(magrittr)
out <- sports[, {
  vec <- sort(unique(c(start_date, end_date)));
  .(sd = vec[-length(vec)], ed = vec[-1]);
}, by = .(id) ] %>%
  .[, ed := pmin(ed, shift(sd, type = "lead") - 1e-5, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(id) ] %>%
  sports[., on = .(id, start_date <= sd, end_date >= ed) ] %>%
  .[ !is.na(sport), ] %>%
  .[, val := 1L ] %>%
  dcast(id + start_date + end_date ~ sport, value.var = "val", fill = 0)
out
#       id start_date   end_date sportA sportB
#    <int>     <Date>     <Date>  <int>  <int>
# 1:     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-14      1      0
# 2:     1 2000-01-15 2000-01-31      1      1
# 3:     1 2000-02-01 2000-02-02      1      0
# 4:     1 2002-01-15 2003-02-28      1      1
# 5:     1 2003-03-01 2006-03-19      0      1
# 6:     2 2014-03-12 2014-04-02      1      0
# 7:     2 2016-10-14 2017-02-09      1      0
# 8:     2 2017-02-10 2017-02-19      1      1
# 9:     2 2017-02-20 2017-05-19      1      0
```

Walk-through:

- the first `sports[, {...}]` produces just the feasible date-ranges, per-`id`; it will produce more than needed, and these are filtered out a little later; I combine this with a slight offset to `end_date` so that rows are mutually exclusive (second note above); while they *appear* to be full-days separated, they are only separated by under 1 second; I add `secdiff` to show this here:

  ```r
  sports[, {
    vec <- sort(unique(c(start_date, end_date)));
    .(sd = vec[-length(vec)], ed = vec[-1]);
  }, by = .(id) ] %>%
    .[, ed := pmin(ed, shift(sd, type = "lead") - 1e-5, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(id) ] %>%
    .[, secdiff := c(as.numeric(sd[-1] - ed[-.N], units="secs"), NA), by = .(id) ]
  #        id         sd         ed   secdiff
  #     <int>     <Date>     <Date>     <num>
  #  1:     1 2000-01-01 2000-01-14 0.8640000
  #  2:     1 2000-01-15 2000-01-31 0.8640000
  #  3:     1 2000-02-01 2000-02-02 0.8640000
  #  4:     1 2000-02-03 2002-01-14 0.8640000  # will be empty post-join
  #  5:     1 2002-01-15 2003-02-28 0.8640000
  #  6:     1 2003-03-01 2006-03-19        NA
  #  7:     2 2014-03-12 2014-04-02 0.8640001
  #  8:     2 2014-04-03 2016-10-13 0.8640001  # will be empty post-join
  #  9:     2 2016-10-14 2017-02-09 0.8640001
  # 10:     2 2017-02-10 2017-02-19 0.8640001
  # 11:     2 2017-02-20 2017-05-19        NA
  ```
- btw, the first operation on `sports[..]` in the previous bullet is `{`-blockized for a slight boost in efficiency, choosing to not `sort(unique(c(start_date, end_date)))` *twice*;
- left join `sports` onto this, on `id` and the date-ranges; this will produce `NA` values in the `sport` column, which indicates the date ranges that were programmatically made (with a simple sequence of dates) but no sports are assigned; these not-needed rows are removed by the `!is.na(sport)`;
- assigning `val := 1L` is purely so that we have a value column during reshaping;
- `dcast` reshapes and fills the missing values with `0`.

Comment: Many thanks for this excellent solution and walk-through, although I must admit that it is slightly above my pay grade. My question is whether it would be possible to "correct the date display" (or add back what was removed earlier) as a final step? The idea is to later predict, let's say, "injury rates" during periods in which the individuals played different sports. This will involve additional non-equi joins and it's therefore important for the overlapping dates (on the day-level) to be correct in that step. This might perhaps not be an issue?

Comment: Your sample data is inconsistent, so I'm not sure what you really mean. If you mean you want the `end_date` to be restored to the original values (and therefore have truly-overlapping `end`/`start` between rows), then ... sure, just test if it is within `1.1e-5` of the next `start_date` and add `1e-5` back to it if true.